# Android bluetooth scan (without LE) get informations from BluetoothDevice object

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to get informations such as minor, major and UUID (for iBeacon) in BluetoothDevice object with a Bluetooth scan (no LE) ?

```
private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val action: String = intent.action!!
        when(action) {
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                val device: BluetoothDevice? =
                    intent?.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                if (device?.name != null) {
                    Log.d("BLUTOOTHSCAN", "${device?.toString()}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With BLE scan i can have them from ScanResult object :

```
fun manageResult(scanResult: ScanResult?) {
    if (scanResult != null) {
        val scanRecord = scanResult.scanRecord
        val iBeaconManufactureData = scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData(...)
        if (iBeaconManufactureData != null && iBeaconManufactureData.size >= 23) {
            val resultBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(iBeaconManufactureData)
            val uuidA = resultBuffer.getLong(2)
            val uuidB = resultBuffer.getLong(10)
            val uuid = UUID(uuidA, uuidB)
            val major = resultBuffer.getShort(18)
            val minor = resultBuffer.getShort(20)
            ...
```

My goal is to scan beacons without need for location permission.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are two different radio technologies that were merely specified by the same organisation and therefore have a similar name.